# Invert .ico file in Python

Tags: python, image, negation

I am trying to invert the icon which is .ico file depending on the windows theme .
Depending on the them of windows, I will try to invert the tray icon.
I haven't found any way to achieve this.

How to invert the icon using python 2.7 ?

```
def get_hicon(self, icon):
        hicon = None
        hinst = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
        if icon and os.path.isfile(icon):
            icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
            ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSMICON)
            ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSMICON)
            hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst,
                                        icon,
                                        win32con.IMAGE_ICON,
                                        ico_x,
                                        ico_y,
                                        icon_flags)
  return hicon
```

I used this code to get the icon

Comment: Can't you live with two prestored icons ?

Comment: yes if this doesn't work I will go ahead with that approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize Pillow, invert the image and save it to a temporary file which will auto-delete after the context manager (with block) exits

```py
# pip install pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with NamedTemporaryFile() as file, Image.open("image.ico") as img:
    old_mode = img.mode  # loaded as RGBA!

    rgb = img.convert("RGB")
    inverted = ImageOps.invert(rgb)
    inverted = inverted.convert(old_mode)

    inverted.save(file, format="ICO", quality=100)
    file.seek(0)  # rewind so it can be read again
    print(file.name)
    # /tmp/tmpjo7pa_r6
    # load/read icon here, probably self.get_hicon(file.name)
# file is automatically deleted here
```